# use tailwind classes into styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

Can I use tailwind classes ( like colors ) into the styled-components ?
I want to use some classes instead of CSS styles to style my components
this is the way add class in styled-components:

```
const Button = styled.button.attrs(props => ({
  className: "small",
}))`
 /* other styles */
`;
```

so unlike styles, attrs className is only one single string, and I want to add classes for size, color, display and etc.
I have to concat them all every time, is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use macro, I suggest trying [`twin.macro`](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro):

```
import tw, { styled } from 'twin.macro'

const Input = styled.input`
  color: purple;
  ${tw`border rounded`}
  ${({ hasHover }) => hasHover && tw`hover:border-black`}
`
const Component = () => <Input hasHover />
```