# Typings when injecting class name into styled components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Please help me to fix my typings.

I want to inject class names into styled components.
I made this function:

```
type IntrinsicElementsKeys = keyof { div: any, a: any } /* could be keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements */

export function elementWithClass(e: IntrinsicElementsKeys, customClassName: string) {
    /* [2] if I don't force the type ts does not allow me to call se.attrs() */
    const se = styled[e] as ThemedStyledFunction<typeof e, any>
    
    const res = se.attrs(props => ({
        className: customClassName + " " + (props.className || "")
    }))``

    /* [1] if I don't force "any" then I cannot use native props such as "href" */
    return res as any;
}
```

I want to get rid of the "any" at [1], but if I do that and call the component as below:

```
const Link = elementWithClass("a", "rick-roll")

const MyElement: React.FC<{ /* props */ }> = props => <Link href="http://rick-roll.com">rick</Link>
```

Then TS complains that "href" is an unknown props.

**So my question is: how do I fix my typings?**

**Note 1:** If I remove the "as" at [2] then TS complains that

```
Each member of the union type '(<U, NewA extends Partial<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; } & U> & { ...; } = {}>(attrs: Attrs<...>) => ThemedStyledFunction<...>) | (<U, NewA extends Partial<...> & { ...; } = {}>(attrs: Attrs<...>) => ThemedStyledFunction<...>)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

**Note 2:** This question is similar to
[use tailwind classes into styled-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454969/use-tailwind-classes-into-styled-components)
but is more specific on how to fix the typing with the specific method I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the first thing you should be thinking is that if you want the return type to be different depending on the input, you should most likely be **including generics**.

So, let's tackle that!

```
type IntrinsicElementsKeys = "div" | "a"; /* could be keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements */

// 1st step, let's introduce the generic inside the function
export function elementWithClass<T extends IntrinsicElementsKeys>(e: T, customClassName: string) {

// 2nd step, let's pass it in ThemedStyledFunction
    const se = styled[e] as ThemedStyledFunction<T, any>;

// 3rd step, pass in the generic into the `attrs` function
    const res = se.attrs<T>(props => ({
        className: customClassName + " " + (props.className || "")
    }))``

    /* [1] if I don't force "any" then I cannot use native props such as "href" */
    return res;
}

const Link = elementWithClass("a", "rick-roll")
const MyElement: React.FC<{ /* props */ }> = props => <Link href="http://rick-roll.com">rick</Link> // all good

const Link1 = elementWithClass("div", "rick-roll")
const MyElement1: React.FC<{ /* props */ }> = props => <Link1 href="http://rick-roll.com">rick</Link1> // error
```

Just follow the steps below, and the props types will be inferred just fine!

1. Introduce a generic to take in the element;
2. Add the generic to the `ThemedStyledFunction`;
3. Add the generic to the `attrs` function;

Here is a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=100&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQFCiSxyowCeANlgCYA0cA3nAAqACywguAZVYdOAMQCuAO3zAIiuAF84REuWbsuAWlwlIirIpipaNVmCxwAkpajBFqYLgCiHcZdQA0lgs6AC85JzAAG5kcAA%205MhkANxwAPRIJvJsnHAARg4A1sEQBHAAUhIAGgB0zjCu7p4%20YhZWiGk0NFgAHgyESipqcFi%20bQDqwDDCAMJsaKgAPIIjPTAWnOj1jR7eY-5BIQB8ABRYAFxCvLjyzCRzCwByyOKXzI0A5gCU-DRw-%20kkABtABMAF04MAyo44Jw1AByQjQXAOaaolj2ODtOFYdCKCDwZBsNgQADucHEWIgcFwRLYTCwNWQMAaqBOPwQnQBNLUzAZcHC%20hkQKwELQQlE4k4UgMckGMFUimWvGQihYR2SfwBWv%20Jnc8EoYQZTJZUCWglOYGIYDCRzgJz4Ou5NPmqFQz1eNNuMHurvdLwcAGpyCHgycrRAbTVcH6PQ44gkyGQvk6NF8vgADDNdbkZOBAgCMEKhTlhCKRUBRiTVsTR6hhtMU%20PgtwcimZ0QcEZtTHkuGEKHQZGElAIsU5TsoMHkUHUhs1Gi6ND1fIAMm5CgKRvsYJNpg83ScyEleBRPIVDMRicnl7z4ABZFgtPwwS7YPAwGqyGaLAR57voJymh2uEAECnaizroom4jlgBChMOLJgOcaRpK4uAXlebDRiQZBHOhhSLGkUGFEcQA) which you can use to play around also.

Comment: Oh thank you !!! I had tried generic parameters, but somehow I did not figure out the "se.attrs<T>". This was the missing bit.

Comment: Somehow I add to write "as unknown as ThemedStyledFunction<T, any>;" because tsc started to complain that "Conversion of type 'ThemedStyledInterface<DefaultTheme>[T]' to type 'ThemedStyledFunction<T, any, {}, never>' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first."